Derivation of Noether's current
I've got a question regarding the derivation of Noether's current from QFT for Gifted Amateur.

The 2nd term in equation 10.14 vanishes in the action. The textbook says it vanishes when integrated over a large enough volume according to the divergence theorem, I however do not get the difference between why the first term doesn't vanish and the second term does.
I thought it'd just be that the integration over the whole space so there's naturally 0 flux out of a volume so gigantic in size, but then it doesn't explain the first term to me.
It'd be a great help to provide some visualisation tool for such integrals and how to internalise it.

Hi. Please do not use images/screenshots for quoting text and equations. Instead, type the relevant passage (and use MathJax).

The second term is a total derivative, so when integrated over the volume you just get the surface terms, which is Stoke's Theorem. Now if you take the volume you're integrating over to be very large, what concerns you will be the value of these surface terms at some arbitrarily distant boundary, where we generally (up to some not relevant non-trivialities) impose the dynamical fields to vanish. This means the entire surface term will vanish as well.

@FranDahab thank you for the response. But wouldn't divergence theorem be more applicable here since the total derivative term takes the form of divergence? I don't see how Stokes theorem is exactly applicable here.

@Loopy I should've been more specific. When I mention Stokes' Theorem I'm referring to the generalized version, the elementary Calculus Stokes' theorem, Divergence theorem and Green theorem are all specific cases of it. In this context, yes, you can use it interchangeably with Divergence theorem.
